# Is it possible to tell python to read a certain file header

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a file converter and it just helps to make python be able to differentiate the different files through the header

Answer (score 2):

Python can read binary files, yes, and you could use that facility to read just the header of a file format, provided you know what you are looking for. But I suspect that that is not what you are asking.

There is no standard library functionality to have it *recognise* files by their header; there are some *specialised* modules such as [`imghdr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imghdr.html) and [`sndhdr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sndhdr.html) but nothing generic.

Perhaps you were looking for a Python library wrapping the `libmagic` functionality, which is a UNIX service for detecting the file type. There are several wrappers available, including [`filemagic`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/filemagic) and [`python-magic`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-magic).